# Dynamic property name in typescript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I get data from a search engine in a way like this:

```
const resultDe = { details_de: "Ein paar Informationen", foo_de:{bar:"barDe"}, code: "1C60" }
const resultEn = { details_en: "Some information", foo_en:{bar:"barEn"} code: "1C60" }
```

I know the names of the properties but some properties have language dependend suffixes like `_de` or `_en`. Is there a way to type such data with typescript?

Something like:

```
type Result = {
  `details_${lang}`: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Lang = 'de' | 'en'
type Result = {
    [Property in `details_${Lang}`]: string
}

const result: Result = { details_en: 'foo', details_de: 'bar' }
```

Comment: My project is in strict mode and is showing, "Property is defined but never used" warning, any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 3):

You can [use template literals to create types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) like this, for example:

```
type LanguageResult<LangCode extends string> = Record<`details_${LangCode}`, string>;

const enResults: LanguageResult<'en'> = {
  details_en: 'test',
};

const enResults: LanguageResult<'de'> = {
  details_en: 'test', // <- Error
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5IgJQgZxQG2AB55kBhAewBNoIAPYCBKnKHYAJwEtkA+KALxRsAYwocqRAAY1gcLvhwB9ACQBvUkko0AvlIA0bTjyS8A3ACgLYhOyhNseQjgBcsRKnRZcBYgHImP34hNQsoKFl5RSUmNz9Gdj99Cx1LawpbYHsER19Xd2Q0DFzCIj8aIMEoUPDIhWVYqHjcYCSoAHp2qCIAWigAUQ4OcRTLIA)

---

If you don't know what strings you're going to need, you can simply use the widest possible type (i.e. `string` itself) to allow any of these codes. For example:

```
type LanguageResult<LangCode extends string = string> = Record<`details_${LangCode}`, string>;

const anyResults: LanguageResult = {
  details_en: 'test',
  details_de: 'test',
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5IgJQgZxQG2AB55kBhAewBNoIAPYCBKnKHYAJwEtkoBeNpx5IAfPyjYAxhQ5UiAAxrA4XfDgD6AEgDepJJRoBfeQBpB3ZCIDcAKBvSE7KIhDY8hHAC5YiVOiy4BMDi2jZQUEoqaupM3gDkjOxxJmEREMqqGjTxicDJNoa2QA)

Comment: @FelHa I've edited my answer to include an example of how to use a type like this without prior knowledge of the language codes that will be used.